# How to find the xpath in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[image]

I need to find the xpath for the line highlighted in the image; the page is dynamic.

I tried this:

```
//td[contains(text(),'Ricardo')]
```

But gave me an error

> ```
>  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>  element: Unable to locate element:
>  {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[contains(text(),'Ricardo')]"}
> ```

Comment: please provide us with more information.  more of the HTML, or even a link to the target web page, would be helpful.  Also, you say that you are looking for "the line in the image highlighted text", do you want to have an xpath to a row that has a column that's been highlighted?  something else?

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Ricardo']"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to inspect the elements on a page. In the console window, you can then just right click the element you want and copy the Xpath. Once you've copied it, paste in following code: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("paste here")`. You might see that within the xpath there are double brackets and you will need to replace these by single brackets.

[image: How to get xpath for an element on page]